# How do I avoid bugs where I use the wrong version of data?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, immutability, monads

I'm trying to learn functional programming zen, so I'm writing a simple-ish compiler using purely functional programming: Scala, with no 'var' anywhere, and no mutable structures.

I have a cache for "already evaluated functions" to speed up compilation and avoid infinite recursion in some cases. In an imperative approach, this would have been a reference to a large mutable hash map somewhere. But in the functional approach, it's more like the below code (heavily simplified and paraphrased, forgive any syntax mistakes).

```
def compileAdd(
      cache0: Cache,
      uncompiledLeftSubExpr: UncompiledExpr,
      uncompiledRightSubExpr: UncompiledExpr)
: (Cache, CompiledExpr) = {
   val (cache1, compiledLeftSubExpr) =
         compileExpression(cache0, uncompiledLeftSubExpr)
   val (cache2, compiledRightSubExpr) =
         compileExpression(cache1, uncompiledRightSubExpr)
   val newExpression =
         AddExpression(compiledLeftSubExpr, compiledRightSubExpr)
   (cache2, newExpression)
}
```

However, imagine if I had a bug where the last line was:

```
   (cache1, newExpression)
```

I do this *all the time*. This is my leading source of post-refactor bugs; after moving code around, I inevitably forget to update one of the "version numbers" and accidentally use an old version.

Is this a common mistake? How does one avoid it?

I would use do-syntax, but that strikes me as just a more complicated "var". I must be thinking about this wrong...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is uncommon, because everyone is using `State` ([scalaz](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/State.html), [cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/state.html)).
If you use `State`-monad (e.g. from one of the mentioned libraries), your example should look somewhat like this:

```
def compileAdd(
  uncompiledLeftSubExpr: UncompiledExpr,
  uncompiledRightSubExpr: UncompiledExpr
): State[Cache, CompiledExpr] = for {
   compiledLeftSubExpr <- compileExpression(uncompiledLeftSubExpr)
   compiledRightSubExpr <- compileExpression(uncompiledRightSubExpr)
} yield AddExpression(compiledLeftSubExpr, compiledRightSubExpr)
```

or rather

```
def compileAdd(
  left: UncompiledExpr,
  right: UncompiledExpr
): State[Cache, CompiledExpr] = for {
   a <- compileExpression(left)
   b <- compileExpression(right)
} yield AddExpression(a, b)
```

This assumes that `compileExpression` also has signature

```
def compileExpression(u: UncompiledExpr): State[Cache, CompiledExpr]
```

and that all the imports with implicits conversions providing the `for-yield` syntax are included.

Comment: I believe you are missing the `cache0` value as the initial state.

Comment: @BobDalgleish Where am I missing `cache0`? I'm not running anything. The initial state of the cache is supplied at the very end, when the entire transformation step which requires the `Cache` is composed and executed using `run`.

Comment: How is this different from using 'var'? Should I just switch to using var instead? Also, I believe cach0 is indeed missing, where would it go?

Comment: @Verdagon `cache0` would be inserted "at the end of the world", when you have composed the complete task that requires the cache: `val job = compileEntireCompilationUnit(uncompiledCompilationUnit); job.run(cache0)`. Whether you "need" it or not, is a design choice. If instead of a whole bunch of methods like `compileAdd`, `compileExpression` etc. you had just a single invokation of one central "Traverse-like" recursion scheme that works with arbitrary monads and applicatives, then it might make more sense to work with `State[Cache, ...]`, because you'd have to specify it in one single place.

Comment: Got it! That makes sense. I have to think of it like "compileAdd is returning a function." (what you would call a monad). Thanks!

Comment: @Verdagon The last sentence might seem a bit dense... The point is: all these abstractions allow you to separate the recursive traversal of the data structure (which depends on the "shape of the expressions"), from the actual operations that are performed on those expressions: whether it's a mutually recursive top-down traversal to check some property that returns a `Boolean`, or a stateful traversal with a cache that compiles the expression to some lower-level operations, those two rather different traversals might reuse same "generic recursion scheme". For this, `State` is more useful.

Comment: Thanks! Where can I read up on this separation and its benefits? I'm unfamiliar with this way of thinking. Specifically, I'm wondering why using the state monad is better than just using a 'var' for my cache inside the function. Any pointers on where I could learn the difference?

Comment: @Verdagon Scala does not enforce that you express all state changes through the `State` monad. The Haskell-people *must* always do it. I guess one could consider it a good permanent exercise at getting used to monads and all that... But in Scala you can decide: is the `State` important enough that you want to keep it under the control of type system (explicitly declare `State` as return type), or is it rather unimportant so you can allow yourself to sweep the side effects on the cache under the rug? Maybe it's OK to use mutable cache - it's your design decision.